# Problem with desktop on Precise 12.04

Tags: 12.04, desktop-environments

My desktop looks like this:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/310276/Screenshot%20from%202013-11-21%2012%3A17%3A41.png

I am not quite sure how this happened, but it could be after a recent software update.  I have tried to change the Wallpaper picture under System Settings / Appearance, but this makes no difference.

I have also tried to reset unity (unity --reset) but this has made no difference.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance.

Grové

Comment: link shows 404 error please update it.

Comment: Please check again. It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to login into `virtual console`,and run the below commands on it,

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity
sudo shutdown -r now
```

After restarted,you will get back to your default desktop.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Will give it a go and report back. Hope it does not wipe too many of my setting.

Comment: if it wokrs,select my answer as right one.